# Variation of Kruskal's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, kruskals-algorithm

Suppose G is an undirected graph with n vertices, there are weighted edges between each pair of vertices. Can you construct a tree in following structure:

v_1-v_2-v_3-...-v_n such that each node in the tree corresponding to a vertex in G and each node only has one child except the leaf. Also the total weight of the tree edges is minimized.

If use an algorithm similar to Kruskal’s Algorithm: sort all weights of edges in the original graph in ascending order. Starts from the minimal weight edge, if add this edge does not violate the tree structure described above, then add this one in the final tree, otherwise, move on to the next.

Can this algorithm give the tree with minimal weights? If not, is it possible to find an algorithm to get this tree?

Comment: This looks very similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path

Comment: @mcdowella Yeah, I am trying to solve a traveling salesmen problem using A* algorithm and I am constructing my heuristic function. Seems like what I am trying to come up here is the problem itself. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can, but it may not. Consider a 4-node graph with edge weights as follows:

```
AB:   3
AC:   1
AD: 100
BC:   2
BD: 100
CD:   2
```

The minimal tree is ABCD with length 7, but your algorithm will always start with the (length 1) edge AC which is not part of the minimal tree required.

Comment: I think you are correct. Is there any algorithm that can always return the tree required?

Comment: @ZigZagZebra: Sure, but it takes exponential time, because this problem (Hamiltonian Path) is NP-hard.